# что обозначает этот код

Tags: javascript

изучал код простой игры змейки на js и не понимаю два фрагмента кода.

1)не понимаю саму формулу. знаю что такое рандом и раунд, но не понимаю, зачем нужно умножать и для чего вычитать и слагать

```
let posX = Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 3) + 1);
```

2) я так понимаю, это спецсимволы,но всё равно не могу понять, что делает код. понимаю, что он ищет селектор, а как именно не понимаю

```
let snakeBody = [document.querySelector('[posX = "' + coordinates[0] +'"][posY = "' + coordinates[1] + '"]')];
```

```js
let container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
container.classList.add('container');

for (let i=1; i<101; i++) {
  let excel = document.createElement('div');
  container.appendChild(excel);
  excel.classList.add('excel');
}

let excel = document.querySelectorAll('.excel');
let x = 1;
let y = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < excel.length; i++) {
    if (x > 10) {
      x = 1;
      y--;
    }
    excel[i].setAttribute('posX', x);
    excel[i].setAttribute('posY', y);
    x++;
}

function generateSnake() {
  
    let posX = Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 3) + 1); 
    let posY = Math.round(Math.random()* (10 - 3) + 1);
    return [posX, posY];
}

let coordinates = generateSnake();
let snakeBody = [document.querySelector('[posX = "' + coordinates[0] + '"][posY = "' + 
coordinates[1] + '"]')];
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 200px ;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #cccccc;
}

.excel {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px; 
}

.bodySnake {
  background-image: url(bodySnake.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.head {
  background-image: url(tanya.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Snake</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 3) + 1)
```

Это случайное число от 1 до 8, `Math.random()` вернет от 0 до 1 значение, умножаем на 7 (10-3) разница только из-за подгонки кода, возможно думали ввести переменную. Далее добавляем минимальное значение, это 1. Получится от 1 до 8. Т.к. переменная не целая ее округляют `round`.

```
let snakeBody = [document.querySelector('[posX = "' + coordinates[0] +'"][posY = "' + coordinates[1] + '"]')];
```

Назначают переменной snakeBody элемент который отбирают по заданному селектору. Т.к. селектор генерируется то нужны координаты змеи X и Y, их берут из переменной `coordinates` которая получена их фукнции `generateSnake()` с результирующими X и Y.

Answer (score 1):

Такие танцы с бубном вокруг math.rand нужны чтоб получить удобный генератор случайного числа в диапазоне от минимального до максимального, т.к. сам метод rand возвращает значение в диапазоне от 0 до 1, а чаще всего нужно значение между какими-то более понятными приземлёнными числами. Конкретно тут в примере происходит следующее:

```
// берём случайное число от 0 до 1
Math.random()

// умножая его на 7 (10 - 3) получаем случайное число от 0 (0 * 1) до 7 (1 * 7)
Math.random() * (10 - 3)

// сдвигаем диапазон на 1 вверх и вместо "от 0 до 7" получаем случайное "от 1 до 8"
Math.random() * (10 - 3) + 1

// округляем т.к. нужна координата по X, а не float-значение
Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 3) + 1);
```

Вот и всё, никакой магии. В итоге получаем "случайное целое число от 1 до 8".

А про селекторы сначала почитайте что это и как работают. Вопрос слишком общий. https://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css_selectors.asp

Comment: хорошо, тогда немного конкретизирую вопрос по селекторам. где можно найти пояснение синтаксиса этого отбора? я не понимаю для чего используются двойные ковычки. то, что вы скинули, я плюс-минус выучил, за исключением редко использующихся

Comment: @СотниЛичностей двойные кавычки просто чтоб заключить в них строковое значение; `[attrName="attrValue"]` - найдёт все тэги у которых указанный атрибут имеет указанное значение